# Groovy: how to make .groovy script as windows service

Tags: windows, service, groovy

How do I make a .groovy script into a windows service? This link http://groovy.codehaus.org/Windows+Services was not good for me, because I am using Win Serv 2008 64-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the process of doing the same thing for the first time.  After some research and some guidance it looks like a nice way of doing this is to use gradle.  After the initial setup, building the project will create a windows and Unix service for you.

There is also a Gradle wrapper so you can run the services even if you can't install gradle on the server itself.

http://www.gradle.org/ 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle